# how can I define XPATH for a span with same class in multiple spans?

Tags: html, xpath

I have division with class ="viewSaveDietData" that contains spans with same class name. I am not able to differentiate the XPATHS of the different spans. Please tell me the XPATH of the individual spans..

```
<div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Created By:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer"><b style='color:#386AA1;'><a href="/www/community/ProfileWall.aspx?f=FitClick" title="FitClick">FitClick</a></b> on Jan 27, 2012</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Users:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">3,403 (<a href="/online_weight_loss_support?cdID=23982">Find someone using this diet</a>)</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Comments:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer"><a href="#jump-to-comments">Be the first!</a></span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Diet Category:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">Balanced</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Diet Plan Length:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">Ongoing</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Meals Per Day:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">3 meals, 4 meals, 5 meals, 6 meals</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Target Gender:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">Women and men</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Weight Goal:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">Lose weight, Maintain weight, Gain weight</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Cooking Difficulty:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">Easy</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                    <div class="viewSaveDietTitle" >Tags:</div><div class="viewSaveDietData" ><span class="Answer">52.5:22.5:25 Macronutrient Ratio</span></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I want to get the xpath of "Balanced"

Comment: What XPath expressions have you tried, and what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but it sounds like you're looking for something like

```
//div[@class='viewSaveDietTitle'][. = 'Diet Category']/
     following-sibling::div[1][@class='viewSaveDietData']/span/text()
```

This will select the text of the span that's a child of the div whose class is `viewSaveDietData`, which immediately follows a div containing the title string 'Diet Category'. In other words, my understanding of your question is, how to select a particular span based on the title of the associated `div`.

If you just want to select a span based on its order in the document, you could use

```
(//span[@class = 'Answer'])[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways that I just tested (via the firefox selenium plugin  and also the firefox xpath plugin) are:

```
//div[@class="viewSaveDietData"]/span[contains(text(), "Balanced")]
```

Also (more specificly):

```
//div[@class="viewSaveDietData"]/span[contains(@class, 'Answer') and text()="Balanced"]
```

Just by position with:

```
//div[@class="viewSaveDietData"][4]/span
```

By Answer span alone (doesn't depend on being in the div) with

```
//span[contains(@class, 'Answer') and text() = "Balanced"]
```

(or more simply)

```
//span[@class="Answer" and text()="Balanced"]
```

---

So:

```
//div[@class="viewSaveDietData"]/span[contains(@class, 'Answer') and text()="Balanced"]
```

is most specific which of course means it's most likely to be specific in selecting the desired elements but also will be more affected by page changes.

Comment: I don't want to compare it with Balanced. Actually I want the xpath such that if it would be any other data at the place of Balanced, then also it gives the exact value in place of balanced..

Answer (score 0):

Got something similar to Larsh, but using /*/ instead of // as this makes search quicker. If titles are unique and if you are interested in answer for Diet Category the below code or one from LarsH should be good.

```
/*/div[@class="viewSaveDietTitle" and text()="Diet Category:"]/following-sibling::div[1]/span/text()
```